# Do any other Jedi own droids?

Tags: star-wars, droids

> LUKE: Then the droid does belong to you.
>
> BEN: Don't seem to remember ever owning a droid. Very interesting...

Obi-Wan says he never owned a droid (though he did have [an astromech attached to his ship](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/R4-P17)).

Through the movies, it seems as though Anakin is the only Jedi to own a droid.

**Prior to Luke, do any other Jedi besides Anakin personally own a droid?**

Comment: About your Ben point, having a astromech attached to the ship doesn't mean that he owns it. A police man don't own the radio transmitter in his police car patrol.

Comment: I think the same goes for Ahsoka. She has an astromech droid that she uses pretty consistently but it's rarely seen outside the ship http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/R7-A7

Comment: I'm guessing this all goes back to Jedi forgoing material possesions as part of their lifestyle.  They might use droids, but they don't claim ownership of them.

Comment: @guillelon, right and that's why I didn't make the argument that he *did* own one, but wanted to highlight it. For all I'm aware, it was just assigned to him for the mission.

Comment: Revan owned Hk-47.This was after he left the jedi order though. http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/HK-47

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To begin with, it's worth pointing out that the [novelisation of the Revenge of the Sith](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novel)) film makes it explicitly clear that Anakin didn't *own* Artoo, he was merely looking after him for Padmé:

> Padme’s life back when she had been Queen of Naboo, not to mention
>   helping the nine-year-old Anakin destroy the Trade Federation’s Droid
>   Control Ship, breaking the blockade and saving the planet. The Royal
>   Engineers of Naboo’s aftermarket wizardry made their modified R-units
>   the most sought after in the galaxy; he’d tried to protest, but she
>   had silenced him with a soft finger against his lips and a gentle
>   smile and a whisper of “After all what does a politician need with an
>   astromech?” “But I’m a Jedi-“
>
> “That’s why I’m not giving him to you,” she’d said with a smile. “I’m
>   asking you to look after him. He’s not really a gift. He’s a friend.”

That all being said, the [Clone Wars Character Encyclopedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars_Character_Encyclopedia) specifically refers to R7-A7 as "Ahsoka's Astromech" and makes reference to it being part of a "group of **Jedi Droids**".

[image: R7-A7 Ahsoka's Droid]

It also says that [Plo Koon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Plo_Koon) is particularly attached to his Astromech, refusing to send it for the customary 'memory wipes' for fear of damaging its unique personality.

[image: R7-D4 Plo Koon's Droid]

Beyond this, there are no canon references to Jedi owning droids.

Answer (score 0):

Reven had an astromech in the Old Republic 
And they would all have a ship with a socket for an astromech wether or not they own there own personal astromechs is a mystery to me